# Debian 9.4-- .profile not read on bash login

Tags: bash, bashrc, profile

The .profile file includes a statement to add the $HOME/bin directory to the PATH (if that bin directory exists). This is not being executed on my bash login.

If I manually load the .profile file

```
. .profile
```

then the PATH is set.

On session start, the .bashrc file is read. It includes a statement to read the .bash_aliases file if it exists, and I can see that the aliases are set.

The .profile file includes a statement to read the .bashrc file if it exists so I assume that the bash init should read the .profile where it is now reading the .bashrc.

This isn't happening. Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this excellent answer from @filipe-brandenburger  on this site.

[debian : read order of bash session configuration files inconsistent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439042/debian-read-order-of-bash-session-configuration-files-inconsistent)