# debian : read order of bash session configuration files inconsistent

Tags: bash

The three files are read in this order?

```
.bash_profile
.profile
.bashrc
```

This is not happening when I first open a terminal.

I have trace statements in the files appending to the file init.log. Please take a look at the following. It begins after opening a terminal. I have placed a comment to show where the log picks up after the su command.

```
stephen@debian:~$ cat init.log
reading .bashrc
done reading .bashrc
stephen@debian:~$ su - stephen
Password: 
stephen@debian:~$ cat init.log
reading .bashrc
done reading .bashrc
#
# after su
#
reading .bash_profile
reading .profile
reading .bashrc
done reading .bashrc
done reading .profile
done reading .bash_profile
stephen@debian:~$
```

So the su - login triggers the expected sequence however the initial login reads only the bashrc. This cannot be correct. Can someone explain under what conditions this would occur. I could modify the bashrc and profile files so that the initial read includes all expected files but I would rather get to the root of the problem and fix it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is that bash will look for these three files (in slightly different situations) but will typically only execute one of them.

When running a *login* shell (typically when you log in on a terminal, or when you open a GNOME Terminal or similar, or when you use `su -`), more specifically an interactive login shell, then it will execute the system-wide `/etc/profile` and after that's done, it will look for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile` and execute the **first** of those that it finds.

From the bash man page:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads  and 
>   executes  commands from  the  file  `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`,
>   and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
>   the first one that exists and is readable.  The `--noprofile` option may
>   be  used  when  the  shell  is started to inhibit this behavior.

When bash is executed as an interactive shell, more specifically an interactive non-login shell, then it will read `~/.bashrc` and execute that file.

From the bash man page:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>   reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists. 
>   This may be inhibited by using the `--norc` option.  The `--rcfile`
>   file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file
>   instead of `~/.bashrc`.

What Linux distributions usually do is ship `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` files that chain each other, so that you have more consistent behavior without having to duplicate settings between the files...

For instance, Debian's default `~/.profile` contains this snippet:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

So it's explicitly sourcing `~/.bashrc`, so that both login and non-login interactive shells will all include the customizations added to that file.

Comment: Thank you @Felipe for this thoughtful and instructive response. On opening a terminal (mate-terminal, xterm) I am starting an interactive login shell, correct? And so I should see .bash_profile, .bash_login, .profile in that order but I see only .bashrc. On an su - we read in .bash_profile (if it exists) or if it does not exist then  .profile which pulls in .bashrc. So does this mean that when I start a terminal that I am NOT  starting an interactive login shell, but that when I su in that session or when I ssh in I DO start an interactive login shell? Why that distinction?.

Comment: @StephenBoston yes it's possible that the terminal will give you a non-login interactive shell. Terminals are a blurry area (since you log in into the GUI), many of them offer to configure whether to open a login shell or not. Also commands have that distinction too (`su -` gives you a login shell while plain `su` doesn't, `sudo -i` gives you a login shell while `sudo -s` gives you a non-interactive login shell.) In general, best you can do is ignore that difference, have your `.profile` source `.bashrc` (which is usually done by the distro) and configure everything in `.bashrc`.

Comment: I have copied the PATH setting snippet from the .profile file into the .bashrc and that seems to work. My HOME/bin is added to the PATH for those situations I expect it. However I will keep an eye on it.

Comment: @StephenBoston see also this answer: https://superuser.com/a/183980/879179. Some graphical environments can be configured to read your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, that's probably the best answer... But it's a different question, so maybe you should post that one for your specific graphical environment setup...